# Counting grouped rows from joined tables

Tags: mysql

I am searching for a solution to count grouped rows from a joined table.

Table **Participants**

```
id  |           email           |     date
----+---------------------------+--------------
 1  |      john@example.com     |   14/01/2015
 2  |     sally@mailing.com     |   14/01/2015
 3  |     sally@mailing.com     |   01/01/2015
 4  |     sally@mailing.com     |   20/01/2015
 5  |   edward@halloworld.com   |   13/02/2015
 6  |   edward@halloworld.com   |   15/01/2015
```

Table **Data**

```
pid | fieldid |    data
----+---------+--------------
 1  |    1    |   Dutch
 1  |    2    |   Cheese
 2  |    1    |   German
 2  |    2    |    Soup
 3  |    1    |   German
 3  |    2    |    Bread
 4  |    1    |   German
 4  |    2    |   Sausage
 5  |    1    |   Italian
 5  |    2    | Meat balls
 6  |    1    |   Italian
 6  |    2    |    Pizza
```

I'd like to see how often a user (based on their email address) has participated. But the query below doenst return the expected result:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS participated,
  p.email,
  coalesce(MAX(case when fieldid = 1 then data end), 0) as "language"
FROM participants p 
LEFT JOIN data d 
  ON d.pid = p.id 
GROUP BY p.email
```

Result:

```
participated |           email           |  language
-------------+---------------------------+------------
      2      |     john@example.com      |   Dutch
      6      |    sally@mailing.com      |   German
      4      |  edward@halloworld.com    |   Italian
```

The 'count' result is not what I would expect. It seems to be counted double. This is probably because there are two records in the **Data** table for each record in the **Participants** table.

What would be the correct query to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting double with the data that you have, then you presumably want `count(distinct d.pid)`.

Comment: Thank you! This works, but I am unsure why. Can you elaborate a little?

Comment: Because you seem to want to count distinct values in `d.pid` rather than the number of non-NULL values.